# how to get the column names and their datatypes of parquet file using pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

i have a parquet file on my hadoop cluster ,i want to capture the column names and their datatypes and write it on a textfile.how to get the column names and their datatypes of parquet file using pyspark.

Answer (score 11):

You can simply read the file and use `schema` to access individual `fields`:

```
sqlContext.read.parquet(path_to_parquet_file).schema.fields
```

Answer (score 3):

Use dataframe.printSchema() - Prints out the schema in the tree format.

> > > df.printSchema()
> > >       root
> > >        |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
> > >        |-- name: string (nullable = true)

You can redirect the output of your program and capture that in a text file.