# How to write empty dataframe to parquet file

Tags: pandas, scala, apache-spark, parquet

Am reading data from JDBC and store it to parquet file for further processing.If the table in Jdbc do not have any values there is no parquet file created.
How can I create a parquet file with atleast the column names, if the dataframe is empty?

Comment: hi @minnu 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695537/how-to-get-the-column-names-and-their-datatypes-of-parquet-file-using-pyspark

Comment: How  to write it as a parquet file, I would be reading this file again in my code